# Delete commandbar control while code is executing

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code that creates and deletes a cell menu control.
This control should only be displayed on a certain worksheet, so when the user switches sheet it gets deleted.

The problem I'm having is that part of the code that is called from the control changes the selected sheet and this causes a **Method 'Delete' of object '_CommandBarButton' failed** error.

I'm guessing this is because the button is still *active* while the code is executing, so it can't be deleted.
Does anyone know of any work around for this?

To use the code create a workbook with two worksheets with codenames *Sheet1* and *Sheet2*.
I'm using Excel for Office 365 ProPlus, but I don't think that's part of the issue here.

The code I have:
**ThisWorkbook**

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    DeleteFromCellMenu
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet1" Then AddCellToMenu
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    If Sh.CodeName = "Sheet1" Then
        AddCellToMenu
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)
    DeleteFromCellMenu
End Sub
```

**Normal Module**
The error occurs near the end of the last procedure (`ctrl.Delete`).

```
'''''''''''''''''
'This is the procedure called by the control button.
'''''''''''''''''
Sub Test()
    Sheet2.Select
End Sub

Sub AddCellToMenu()

    Dim Menu(0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim vItm As Variant
    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar

    Menu(0) = "Cell"
    Menu(1) = "List Range Popup"

    'Delete the controls first to avoid duplicates
    Call DeleteFromCellMenu

    For Each vItm In Menu
        Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars(vItm)

        'Add the control button.
        With ContextMenu.Controls.Add(Type:=msoControlButton, Before:=1)
            .Caption = "Create Pre-Alert"
            .Tag = "Customs_Tag"
            .FaceId = 1392
            .OnAction = "'" & ThisWorkbook.Name & "'!" & "Test"
        End With

        ContextMenu.Controls(2).BeginGroup = True

    Next vItm

End Sub

Sub DeleteFromCellMenu()

    Dim Menu(0 To 1) As Variant
    Dim vItm As Variant
    Dim ContextMenu As CommandBar
    Dim ctrl As CommandBarControl

    Menu(0) = "Cell"
    Menu(1) = "List Range Popup"

    For Each vItm In Menu
        'Set ContextMenu to the Cell menu
        Set ContextMenu = Application.CommandBars(vItm)

        'Delete custom controls with the Tag : Customs_Tag
        For Each ctrl In ContextMenu.Controls
            If ctrl.Tag = "Customs_Tag" Then
                ctrl.Delete '<<<ERROR OCCURS HERE.
            End If
        Next ctrl
    Next vItm

End Sub
```

Comment: Not an answer, but why do you need to delete it? Couldn't you just leave it, or hide it?

Comment: If it's only for one sheet, I'd either only add it to the menu when right-clicking on that sheet (delete if another sheet), or use a custom popup menu for that sheet instead.