# Delete temporary option from right click menu

Tags: excel, vba

The following code is sitting in a worksheet called "SPG Summary"

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
      Dim cmdBtn As CommandBarButton, param As String
      
      Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(, , "testBt")
      If Intersect(Target, Range("C21:C42")) Is Nothing Then
        If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then cmdBtn.Delete
        Exit Sub
      End If
        
        If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)
        param = "test param"
        With cmdBtn
            .Tag = "testBt"
            .Caption = "MyOption"
            .Style = msoButtonCaption
            .OnAction = "TestMacro"
        End With
    End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Dim cmdBtn As CommandBarButton
    Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(, , "testBt")
    If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then cmdBtn.Delete
End Sub
```

The TestMacro code is as follows:

```
Sub TestMacro()
    
    Sheets("UPC Summary").Range("A21").Value = ActiveCell.Value
    Application.Goto Sheets("UPC Summary").Range("A1"), True

End Sub
```

If I remove the "Sub Worksheet_Deactivate" the code will work but it means the right click option is still available on the worksheet we have gone to which I would like to stop as that right click menu option should only be available on the "SPG Summary" sheet.

If I try to run it as is I get the following error:

[image]

and errors on the line with the bold italic being what excel colours yellow as the issue "If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then ***cmdBtn.Delete***"

Many thanks in advance, Alan.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59092921/delete-commandbar-control-while-code-is-executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you can't remove the right-click option while its code is still executing.

You could use something like this instead, in the `ThisWorkbook` module:

```vb
Private Sub Workbook_SheetBeforeRightClick(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim cmdBtn As CommandBarButton, param As String
    
    Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").FindControl(, , "testBt")
    
    'adjust sheet name/range to suit
    If Sh.Name = "Data" And Not Intersect(Target, Sh.Range("C21:C42")) Is Nothing Then
        If cmdBtn Is Nothing Then
            Set cmdBtn = Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls.Add(Temporary:=True)
            param = "test param"
            With cmdBtn
                .Tag = "testBt"
                .Caption = "MyOption"
                .Style = msoButtonCaption
                .OnAction = "TestMacro"
            End With
        End If
    Else
        If Not cmdBtn Is Nothing Then cmdBtn.Delete
    End If
      
End Sub
```

Comment: Seamless solution and works like a charm.